# python delete what is between parenthesis in a string

Tags: python

I am working on a way (in python) to get a string before parenthesis. I explain myself :

from a string 'xxx a(b) xxx', i need to look for the string 'b' and get what is before the parentheis , in this case 'a' .

I need to get ride of what is between opening and closing parenthesis, here are more example:

```
xxx a(b) xxx       ==> i need to return a
xxx a((c)b) xxx    ==> i need to return a
xxx a((c)(d)b) xxx ==> i need to return a
```

here is a real case , i have this string :
A="low fat yogurt, sugar, milk chocolate
(sugar, whole cow's milk powder, cocoa butter, cocoa mass, whey powder (cow's milk), lecithin, flavoring),
rice flour, fortified wheat flour (wheat flour, calcium carbonate, iron, niacin, thiamine), rice starch, caramel
(sugar, water), wheat starch, color (caramel), salt, flavoring, emulsifier (mono and diglycerides of fatty acids),
gum arabic, glucose syrup, calcium carbonate, milk caramel (glucose-fructose syrup, sweetened condensed milk (sugar, cow's milk), water),
concentrated lemon juice, cocoa butter, banana: low fat yogurt (cow's milk), sugar, whole milk chocolate (6%) (sugar, whole cow's milk powder,
cocoa butter, cocoa mass, (cow's milk), emulsifier (soy lecithin)), banana puree (2.5%), modified cornstarch,
salt, barley malt, emulsifier (sunflower lecithin), thickener (gum arabic), glucose syrup, modified tapioca starch, coconut oil,
acidity regulator (citric acid), flavorings, concentrated lemon juice, color (beta carotene), vanilla: low fat yogurt (cow's milk),
sugar, milk chocolate (8%) (sugar, whole cow's milk powder, cocoa butter, cocoa mass, whey powder (cow's milk), lecithin, flavoring),
white chocolate (3.5%) (sugar, cocoa butter, whole cow's milk powder, whey powder , flavoring, emulsifier (soy lecithin)),
rice flour, wheat flour, modified cornstarch, wheat fiber, malted barley flour, salt, glucose syrup, gum arabic, thickener (pectin),
flavorings, concentrated lemon juice, flavor, color (beta carotene), cocoa butter"

I need to look for the String : "lecithin"
and get what before parenthesis , on this example , it should be
-milk chocolate
-emulsifier
-emulsifier
-milk chocolate
-emulsifier

I have been working on that for 2 days now, and it is driving me crazy

thank you a lot for your help

Comment: So, is the rule "all alphanumerics between a space and a left paren"?  That's easy to write as a regex, or even with `string.find`.

Comment: no, not that easy, because we don't know where the opening parenthesis is closing !!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this,

```
input = "low fat yogurt, sugar, milk chocolate (sugar, whole cow's milk powder, cocoa butter, cocoa mass, whey powder (cow's milk), lecithin, flavoring), rice flour, fortified wheat flour (wheat flour, calcium carbonate, iron, niacin, thiamine), rice starch, caramel (sugar, water), wheat starch, color (caramel), salt, flavoring, emulsifier (mono and diglycerides of fatty acids), gum arabic, glucose syrup, calcium carbonate, milk caramel (glucose-fructose syrup, sweetened condensed milk (sugar, cow's milk), water), concentrated lemon juice, cocoa butter, banana: low fat yogurt (cow's milk), sugar, whole milk chocolate (6%) (sugar, whole cow's milk powder, cocoa butter, cocoa mass, (cow's milk), emulsifier (soy lecithin)), banana puree (2.5%), modified cornstarch, salt, barley malt, emulsifier (sunflower lecithin), thickener (gum arabic), glucose syrup, modified tapioca starch, coconut oil, acidity regulator (citric acid), flavorings, concentrated lemon juice, color (beta carotene), vanilla: low fat yogurt (cow's milk), sugar, milk chocolate (8%) (sugar, whole cow's milk powder, cocoa butter, cocoa mass, whey powder (cow's milk), lecithin, flavoring), white chocolate (3.5%) (sugar, cocoa butter, whole cow's milk powder, whey powder , flavoring, emulsifier (soy lecithin)), rice flour, wheat flour, modified cornstarch, wheat fiber, malted barley flour, salt, glucose syrup, gum arabic, thickener (pectin), flavorings, concentrated lemon juice, flavor, color (beta carotene), cocoa butter"

# items are separated by comma
x = input.split(',')

# find indexes of lecithin
idx = [i for i,x in enumerate(b) if 'lecithin' in x]

output = []
for i in idx:
    # search for open/close parenthesis in the same item
    if b[i].count('(') >0 and b[i].count(')')>0:
        output.append(b[i].split('(')[0].strip())
    else:  # move backwards counting parenthesis
        p = ''.join(b[i:]).count(')') - ''.join(b[i:]).count('(')
        for j in reversed(range(i)):
            p += b[j].count(')') - b[j].count('(')
            if p == 0:
                break
        output.append(b[j].split('(')[0].strip())
    
print(output)
# ['milk chocolate', 'emulsifier', 'emulsifier', 'milk chocolate', 'emulsifier']
```

Comment: i can have parenthesis after xxx for example 'xxxx(vv)xxx a((c)hi(d)b) xxx(f)xxx'

Comment: Then  do another split, like, `output = input.split(' ')[1].split('(')[0].split(' ')[-1]`

Comment: nope, if only it was that easy, i wouldn't be working on it for 2 days !!!

Comment: You edited the question. Now, this changes everything. The fact that elements were separated by comma was an important information. I edited the answer. The code seems to work for the example given in the question. I hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right way but I have a solution:

Based on the "(" you divide them into a dictionary. The only issue is % shown in () so for now, I have removed them, you can use some other brackets if possible.

```py
A="low fat yogurt, sugar, milk chocolate (sugar, whole cow's milk powder, cocoa butter, cocoa mass, whey powder (cow's milk), lecithin, flavoring), rice flour, fortified wheat flour (wheat flour, calcium carbonate, iron, niacin, thiamine), rice starch, caramel (sugar, water), wheat starch, color (caramel), salt, flavoring, emulsifier (mono and diglycerides of fatty acids), gum arabic, glucose syrup, calcium carbonate, milk caramel (glucose-fructose syrup, sweetened condensed milk (sugar, cow's milk), water), concentrated lemon juice, cocoa butter, banana: low fat yogurt (cow's milk), sugar, whole milk chocolate  (sugar, whole cow's milk powder, cocoa butter, cocoa mass, (cow's milk), emulsifier (soy lecithin)), banana puree , modified cornstarch, salt, barley malt, emulsifier (sunflower lecithin), thickener (gum arabic), glucose syrup, modified tapioca starch, coconut oil, acidity regulator (citric acid), flavorings, concentrated lemon juice, color (beta carotene), vanilla: low fat yogurt (cow's milk), sugar, milk chocolate  (sugar, whole cow's milk powder, cocoa butter, cocoa mass, whey powder (cow's milk), lecithin, flavoring), white chocolate  (sugar, cocoa butter, whole cow's milk powder, whey powder , flavoring, emulsifier (soy lecithin)), rice flour, wheat flour, modified cornstarch, wheat fiber, malted barley flour, salt, glucose syrup, gum arabic, thickener (pectin), flavorings, concentrated lemon juice, flavor, color (beta carotene), cocoa butter"
fin = []
num_left = 0
num_right = 0
temp = ""
dic_name = dict()
id_d = ""

for i in A:
    if (i=="("):
        num_left+=1
        if(num_left==1):
            id_d = temp
            temp = ""
            continue
    elif(i==")"):
       num_right+=1
        num_left-=1
        if(num_left==0):
            val = temp
            dic_name[id_d] = val
            temp= ""
        continue
    
    temp+=i

for key,value in dic_name.items():
    n = value.find("lecithin")
    if(n>0):
        fin.append(key.split(",")[-1])


print(fin)
```

Output:

```
[' milk chocolate ', ' whole milk chocolate  ', ' emulsifier ', ' milk chocolate  ', ' white chocolate  ']
```

Also, I think your answer should be the output that the program is giving, since you want the value of outer parenthesis.